# Trajectory of a ball thrown over a wall, from a height, using cartesian equations and differentiation

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

A person attempts to throw a ball over a wall of height $5m$ that is $12m$ away. It is thrown at a speed of $u ms^{-1}$ from a height of $2m$ at an angle $θ$ to the horizontal. Gravity is $10 ms^{-2}$ for this question.

(i) If the ball just clears the wall, use the cartesian equation of trajectory to find an expression of $u^2$ in terms of $tanθ$.

For this part, I have the general equation of $u^2 = {-gx^2(1+tan^2θ)\over 2(y-xtanθ)}$ but I'm not sure what numbers to input for $x$ and $y$? I assume $x = 12$ but do I put $y = 3$ as it is $3m$ above the starting point of $2m$ or $y = 5$ as the coordiate would be at $5m$?

(ii) Find $u$ when $θ = 45°$.

I think this is easy enough provided I have the right formula for part (i), but I'm not certain what that would be?

(iii) By differentiating a multiple of $u^2$, or otherwise, find the minimum speed at which the ball can be thrown, in order for the wall to be cleared, and the angle at which it must be thrown.

This part is where I'm just completely stuck - I'm not even sure where to begin! Please help!

Comment: It is height relative to the starting point so $y = 3$.

Comment: The formula for $u^2$ is correct for y=3

Answer (score 1):

On the x-axis: $x=u_x(0)\cdot t=u\cdot \cos(\theta)\cdot t$

On the y-axis: $y=y_0+u_y(0)\cdot t-\frac{g\cdot t^2}{2}$

Solve for t in first equation: $t=\frac{x}{u\cos(\theta)}$

Replace in the second equation: $y=y_0+u\sin(\theta)\cdot \frac{x}{u\cos(\theta)}-\frac{g\left(\frac{x}{u\cos(\theta)}\right)^2}{2}$

Simplify and separate terms: $y-y_0=x\tan(\theta)-\frac{gx^2(1+\tan^2(\theta)}{2u^2}$

Solve for $u^2$: $u^2=\frac{gx^2(1+tan^2(\theta)}{2[x\tan(\theta)-(y-y_0)]}, x=12, y=5, y_0=2, g=10$

As you see my formula is a bit more complex than yours. Let me know if you need extra explaining so far.

Now to the differentiating part.

$$u(\theta)=x\sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1+\tan^2(\theta)}{x\tan(\theta)-h}}, h=y-y_0$$

$$u'(\theta)=0\Rightarrow\sqrt{x\tan(\theta)-h}\cdot [2\tan(\theta)(x\tan(\theta)-h)-(1+\tan^2(\theta))\cdot x]=0$$

$$x\tan^2(\theta)-2h\tan(\theta)-x=0$$

$$tan(\theta)=\frac{h\pm \sqrt{h^2+x^2}}{x}, \tan(\theta)\gt 0$$

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{3+ \sqrt{3^2+12^2}}{12}=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}, \theta\approx 52^\circ$$
The minimal value of velocity is $u=12\sqrt{\frac{10}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}\right)^2}{12\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{4}-3}}\approx 12.4 \frac{m}{s}$

Please do your own calculations. Let me know if you find any discrepancies.

Comment: $u(45^\circ)=4\sqrt{10}\frac{m}{s}$ (ii)

Comment: Okay, for the first bit it makes complete sense. I start to get a little lost when you say $u(θ) =x...$ - why is it $u(θ)$ ?

Comment: The speed u is a function of angle $\theta$. $u=\sqrt{u^2}$

Comment: The text of the problem says “find the minimum speed […] and the angle “. This leads to the speed being a function of angle.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also wondering why the question suggest I use a multiple of $u^2$ rather than just u? I can't get my head around this differentiation - it feels a little advanced compared to what I'm used to.

Comment: The reason it says “a multiple of $u^2$ is because when we solve $(u^2)\prime(\theta)=0$, then any constant doesn’t matter. In this case $x^2\cdot \frac{g}{2}=12^2\cdot \frac{10}{2}$.

Comment: In my initial answer I have used the function $f(\theta)=u^2$. However, for clarity I’ve decided to use $f(\theta)=u(\theta)$ in order to outline the dependency of u from $\theta$. The reason either the expression of u or $u^2$ could be differentiated with same result is that $(u^2)\prime=0\Rightarrow 2\cdot u \cdot u\prime=0\Rightarrow u\prime=0$. Both u and $u\prime$ are increasing functions so a minimum of u is also a minimum of $u^2$ for the same $\theta$.